# ansible syntax error - yaml - ansible-galaxy role

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to use the jdauphant.ssl-certs role from the ansible-galaxy.
I am copying the example from their [README](https://github.com/jdauphant/ansible-role-ssl-certs) (last example at bottom of page) exactly but I receive an syntax error message.

This is my playbook.yml file:

```
---
- name: Web01
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  gather_facts: true

  roles:
    - common
    - jdauphant.ssl-certs
      ssl_certs_generate_dh_param: true
    - role: jdauphant.nginx
      nginx_configs:
        ssl:
              - ssl_certificate_key {{ssl_certs_privkey_path}}
              - ssl_certificate     {{ssl_certs_cert_path}}
              - ssl_dhparam         {{ssl_certs_dhparam_path}}
      nginx_sites:
        default:
              - listen 443 ssl
              - server_name _
              - root "/usr/share/nginx/html"
              - index index.html
```

Here is the error message I receive:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to have been in '/home/blah/example/provisioning/development.yml': line 11, column 34, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    - jdauphant.ssl-certs
      ssl_certs_generate_dh_param: true
                                 ^ here

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example says:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
   - role: jdauphant.ssl-certs
     ssl_certs_common_name: "example.com"
```

Your code:

```
    - jdauphant.ssl-certs
      ssl_certs_generate_dh_param: true
```

You are missing `role:`before `jdauphant.ssl-certs`

Comment: Thank you! It's now working.

Comment: I've notified the git repo maintainer to fix the example which contains this error.